# Replacing special characters in Oracle using regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle, character-encoding, oracle9i

I want to replace the below-underlined character with the null value in oracle. I am using below query in Oracle. The query gives the values. But when i copy and paste it in Notepad, the same character is displaying in Notepad.

Query :

SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  column1 IS NOT NULL
AND    REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '[^\u0009\u000a\u000d\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]')

[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me your regexp return TRUE if column1 contains any symbol different from `\u0009\u000a\u000d\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD`. You are sure in this regexp?

Comment: But still i can see the above character after running this query..

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE` doesn't  replace characters, it's  work similar to `LIKE`.

Comment: If you want to exclude rows where column1 contains any symbol from `\u0009\u000a\u000d\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD` you need to change your query `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '[\u0009\u000a\u000d\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]')`

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826 and https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to display the rest of the string, just "delete" the "offending" characters?

Comment: Yes. I got the solution. I did this using below query "SELECT REPLACE(column,CHR(ASCII-char),'')". It works for me. Thanks for your comments